# Drupal- Looking for code to print tweet to node-type.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using the Tweet module in Drupal 7. I need the code to use for printing the tweet field in the node-type.tpl.php. Unfortunately I have been unable to find the correct code to make the link appear in my node. Using contemplate I found the following code;

```
<?php echo $content['tweet']; ?>
<?php echo $content['field_tweet']; ?>
<?php echo render($content['tweet']); ?>
<?php echo render($content['field_tweet']); ?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#theme'] ?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#attributes']['class'][1]?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#attributes']['class'][0]?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#links']['tweet_Twitter']['html']?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#links']['tweet_Twitter']['href']?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#links']['tweet_Twitter']['title']?>
<?php print $node->content['body']['#object']->content['links']['tweet']['#links']['tweet_Twitter']['title']?>
```

But none of them work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($node)` to get an idea of the structure? The `devel` module will also show you this.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code both in the node-type.tpl.php and in the content of the node itself and didn't get anything.

Comment: Do **any** changes to the node-type.tpl.php file reflect on the site? You may be having a caching issue, or node-type.tpl.php might not even be being used.

Comment: yes the node--content-type-name.tpl.php is working fine. It's just that nothing shows up with <?php print_r($node); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tweet module documentation states that it will render in the links section of the node. Add this to node--content-type-name.tpl.php where you want you're tweet links to render:

```
<?php print render($content['links']); ?>
```

And clear the cache.

Comment: I've got the node--content-type-name.tpl.php working correctly the highly modified node shows up just fine. The cache has been cleared over and over. But the code shows nothing...???

Comment: The Tweet module documentation states that it will render in the links section of the node, try this:
    <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

Comment: That worked! Thanks alot. I've been tearing my hair out... you might want to edit your answer to reflect the code on your reply instead of your original comment.